# SharePoint Web Services client that supports 2010 and 2007,

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

Is it possible to support both SharePoint Web Services 2010 and 2007 from the same web services client? or will they need different clients.

How different are the web services from previous versions of SharePoint Web Services.  I can't seem to find any examples of supporting multiple versions of SharePoint Web Services when implementing a client.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know all the SP 2007 Web services work the same in SP 2010.

What's new in SP 2010 is the RESTful service (listdata.svc) which is, according to Microsoft, the preferred way to access list data (rather than Lists.asmx).

Comment: I was starting to assume that but hate assumptions and couldn't find any documentation stating that they where mostly the same.

Comment: You might want to check out http://spservices.codeplex.com . It is a jQuery abstraction for SharePoint Web Services and has some compatibility information. I mainly use Lists.asmx and it works the same in both versions.

Comment: @eaglestorm there is a statement buried in [What's new: Query Enhancements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee534964.aspx): Earlier versions of the SharePoint Foundation product have provided a set of Web services to enable client interaction with SharePoint Foundation deployments. Some of these services, such as List Data Retrieval Web Service, are still supported, in order to provide backward compatibility and interoperability with Web service clients. For best performance and usability, we recommend that you use either the client object model or the ADO.NET Data Services Framework.

Comment: @JanisVeinbergs +1 for your comment, but at the same time the data services framework is still rough on the edges. see this example: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/26038/how-to-avoid-metadata-in-a-rest-response-listdata-svc

Comment: @JanisVeinbergs, so your saying Microsoft is discouraging non .Net based applications from interacting with SharePoint?  as they will need to use web services?

Comment: @eaglestorm I'd recommend that you follow the link posted by Janis Veinbergs for a full review. What is discouraged is the use of earlier Web services when more modern alternatives are provided.

Comment: not much point in discouraging it when the modern alternatives don't work with 2007.

Comment: @eaglestorm the page is explicitly about SharePoint 2010, and only makes sense in that context (except for my comment above...).

Comment: yeah but if u remember the title of the question I asked?

Comment: @eaglestorm I perfectly remember and replied accordingly. Janis just posted a comment, not a direct answer to your question. I think drawing your attention on the risk that some Web services will be deprecated in the future is a good point, especially when SharePoint vnext is around the corner.

Comment: @eaglestorm, that was a copy/passte from the site i linked to and more an answer to "couldn't find any documentation stating that they where mostly the same" not your question :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the namespaces of the service contracts (in the WSDL). If they are the same then the services should be compatible.